# Route not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting an error `404|Not found` , while the route is existing and the debugger is on I have `cleared route cache`but still showing the error, when I `php artisan route:list` it shows `POST      | products/{product}/favourites               | product.fav.store   | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@store` How can I solve this?

controller

```
public function store(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching([$product->id]);

    return back();
}
```

Blade

```
<span class="pull-right">
<a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('product-fav-form').submit();">Add to Fav</a>

<form id="product-fav-form" class="hidden" action="   {{route('product.fav.store', $product) }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field()}}
</form>
</span>
```

Route

```
 Route::post('/products/{product}/favourites', 'HomeController@store')->name('product.fav.store');
```

Comment: `action="   {{route('product.fav.store', $product) }}"` there is space after `action` and before `route` url. and in route you should pass product id. `$product->id`

Comment: I have changed the form looks like this `<form id="product-fav-form" class="hidden" action="{{route('product.fav.store', $product->id) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field()}}
</form>` but still the I get `404` @Laravel

Comment: whats this product variable holds?? and whats the url generated when the 404 page shows??

Comment: first check in your rendered view if the route is formed correctly (with an inspect), if that is correct, try to put exit('route works') as the first line of your function, to see if the route itself at least directs to the function.

Comment: The product variable holds the product information eg.price,image etc  and the url generated is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/6/favourites` @zahidhasanemon

Comment: The route is formed correctly, how do I put that exit route? @MrEvers

Comment: try `dd('ok')` in your controller. check if it goes to the correct controller action.

Comment: @joh As you said `prodcut` holds much information that is why route not work

Comment: @joh You can try to pass product id or product name in a route like `<form action="{{ route('product.fav.store', $product->id) }}" >`

Comment: not as a route, just put it in your function, above $request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching([$product->id]); That way you know your route works up to there, and the issue must be after that exit. Exits are great that way, if you don't know at which point your code stops working

Comment: If i dd('ok') in controller I see the `404` error(same error) @zahidhasanemon

Comment: I have tried to remove `$request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching([$product->id]);` line in controller and replace it with `return 'hello'` but it keeps showing `404` error @MrEvers

Comment: Then the route itself is the problem, is the route inside a group, with middleware perhaps?

Comment: I have tried to put inside a group and outside both method doesn't work @MrEvers

Comment: Last thing I can suggest is trying to post to a test route without parameters `action="/test"` and `Route::post('test','HomeController@test')` then `public function test(){ exit('test'); }`

Comment: does Product with id == 6 actually exist? the route model binding will cause a 404 if it can't find the record

Answer (score 0):

You should change your route like.

```
<form action="{{ route('product.fav.store', ['product' => $product->id]) }}" >
```

Comment: I didn't put it right when I was asking the question but in my code it is like that @Amit Senjaliya

Comment: @joh You have pass `$product` as parameter But `$prodcut` means `id` or `name`

Comment: If I change to `{{ route('product.fav.store', $product->name) }}` I get an error `Missing required parameters for [Route: product.fav.store]` @Amit Senjeliya

Comment: @joh Maybe `$product->name` empty. try to use `product->id`

Comment: If I use `$product->id` it shows `404` error @Amit Senjaliya

Comment: @joh I think parameter pass as an array-like  `<form action="{{ route('product.fav.store', [$product->name]) }}" >`

First check `$product->name` is not empty.

Comment: If I pass that `<form action="{{ route('product.fav.store', [$product->name]) }}` I get `404` error and the url looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products//favourites` also if I change to `[$product->id]` I still get `404` error @Amit Senjaliya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200950/discussion-between-amit-senjaliya-and-joh).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.fav.store', ['product' => $product->id]) }}">
```

Change the controller function

```
public function store(Request $request,$product)
{
$request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching($product);

return back();
}
```

Comment: That is not displaying any errors but it returns the page back without adding the product to favorite (means the button is not working) @jithesh jose

Comment: Can you put a `dd('here')` before `$request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching([$product]);` to check whether the call has reached the controller function or not..

Comment: if I dd('here') it displays here

Comment: Then it's the problem with that call...put `$request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching($product);` and try

Comment: Is not adding the product @jithesh jose

Comment: So the route problem is now fixed..Try to solve the product adding part..I don't know how you are adding it and all..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200955/discussion-between-jithesh-jose-and-joh).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form id="product-fav-form" class="hidden" action="{{route('product.fav.store', $product->name)}}" method="POST">
```

controller :

```
public function store(Request $request, $name) {
    $request->user()->favouriteProducts()->syncWithoutDetaching($name);
    return back();
}
```

Comment: That cause an error `Missing required parameters for [Route: product.fav.store]` @Elonelon